# Send scheduled notifications according to SQLite database data

Tags: android, sqlite, notifications, scheduled-tasks, alarm

I'm making an Android application that reminds the user when he has to take medicines.
This app consists of a list of medicines with some attributes: `name`, `format`, `amount`, `exp_date`, `time`.
For this purpose I created an SQLite database with the table `medicines` and what I want to do is to send notifications to the user at the time retrieved from the table.
I.e. The records in the database have these 3 `time` values: 11:00, 16:00, 21:00.
Whenever the device time and these `time` values coincide, the app sends a notification to the user every day.

I've already read about `AlarmManager`, `NotificationManger` and other stuff but I can't find anything that's kinda specific for me, mostly for the database fetch.
I've already created the most part of the app, the only thing missing is the Notification part. So, if someone has an idea or a link that explains in detail how to do it, I will appreciate it.

I hope to have explained myself in detail and I thank you in advance for any help!

Comment: So what is your problem? Reading data from the DB, or setting up an alarm?

Comment: I already implemented the `DatabaseManager` class. What I need is to retrieve the `time` attribute from the table `medicines` and to store them somewhere in order to create a schedule with them.

Answer (score 1):

create a BroadCastReceiver in your project

```
public class YourReceiver  extends BroadcastReceiver{

    YourDBhelper mdb;



    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        //do stuff what u want 
          mdb = new YourDBhelper(context);//with this u will control of your db

    }
}
```

and register your reciever in manifest as follows

```
<receiver android:name="YourReceiver">
      <intent-filter>
         <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED">
      </action>
      </intent-filter>
   </receiver>
```